# Creating an encrypted file container as a non-root user

Tags: encryption, luks

Linux kernel 3.2.0-64-generic here (Ubuntu LTS if someone is wondering about kernel options / modules).

I have some file space on this Linux server (~ 24 GB). I would like to use this space as an encrypted file that I can mount remotely via sshfs.

I went through the first few steps:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=backup bs=1M count=23000
$ cryptsetup -y luksFormat backup
WARNING!!! Possibly insecure memory. Are you root?

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on backup irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Cannot find a free loopback device.
$
```

Now, I am not root, and cannot become root. It's not a server I administer.

Is there any way I can use the dm-crypt system to let me create an encrypted file container as a non-root user? I have google'd, and it does not look like I can. Bummer if true.

encfs is not available on this server, so I don't have that option. In any case, my two previous experiences with encfs were pretty bad. Due to filename length restrictions, I got mangled backups that I could not recover. Swore off encfs since then.

Advice would be welcome.

Alternative is obvious - create the 24G backup file somewhere else (say a server I own) and then sftp it there in place. Hopefully, then I can at least mount it. But I would like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: You need to be root for this, and for mounting as well.

Comment: How about `sudo modprobe loop` before running `cryptsetup`? You can format the container, but you will not be able to open it. So, you need root.

Comment: Is there a design/security reason why encryption in Linux is walled off from non-root users?

Comment: How set are you on having an encrypted "container"?  You could use gnupg + tar to do the job.  You'd have to write the decrypted stuff to disk (in a dir you've chmod'ed) but assuming you can trust the OS that should be OK.  And if you can't trust the OS... why are you trying to mount an encrypted container anyway?  They could just watch you enter your password.

Comment: Also I'm fairly certain they'd have gpg installed because Debian uses it to sign their repositories.